# Laravel 5.6 Storage::download file not found

Tags: php, laravel, download, storage

I'm using Laravel 5.6, filesystems.php config default.

When file is uploaded I have record in my DB with path column where paths is recorded like - posts/p4NbvgcxHFcT10TwbS2UUJrajifPcqpN3i7iSyyk.png

Symlink was created and files stored in public dir.

```
 $path = $file->store('posts', 'public');
```

This path is recorder to DB, if I want to show e.g. image, I can access it by:

```
{{ asset('/storage/'.$file->path) }}
```

But when I try to force download it get exception - FileNotFoundException
File not found at path:

File download method:

```
  public function downloadFile($id){
    $file = File::find($id);

    //return Storage::download(storage_path()."/app/public/".$file->path, $file->original_name);
    //also tried like this
    return Storage::download(asset('storage/'.$file->path), $file->original_name);
}
```

App running on Windows OS

Comment: what returns `$file->path` property ? try to dump it in downloadFile method

Comment: `{{ asset('/storage/'.$file->path) }}` and `asset('storage/'.$file->path)` might not be same

Comment: dd(
            asset('/storage/'.$file->path),
            asset('storage/'.$file->path)
        ); result is same. $file->path return path like posts/p4NbvgcxHFcT10TwbS2UUJrajifPcqpN3i7iSyyk.png

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Solution was: `return Storage::disk('public')->download($file->path);`

Comment: Gracias tu solución funcionó! Como comentario adicional, **public** deberá ser cambiado por el repositorio que se esté manejando como aws o digitalocean.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`return Storage::download(storage_path('app/public/'.$file->path), $file->original_name);`

Comment: Nope, same error. But storage_path('app/public/'.$file->path) gives correct path to the file. If i write to explorer path returned from this code I can access file, but Storage::download can't see this file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `asset()` you will call file for selected directory. If you can call file on storage folder use `Storage::class` facade